# Dataframe column update with another dataframe values with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe like below named as df

| Name | property | location | messsage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | house | london | recently bought |
| Adam | company | newyork | old one |

Another dataframe like below named as df1

| S.No. | APIname | Up_ApiName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rice | rice_c |
| 2 | Name | Name_new |
| 3 | property | Asset |
| 4 | location | Site |
| 5 | message | comment |

I want update only column names in df where these column should match in df1 APIname then it has to update with values in Up_ApiName

So, New data will be like below

| Name_new | Asset | Site | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | house | london | recently bought |
| Adam | company | newyork | old one |

Comment: Note that message is spelled with 3 times an s in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary with the old column names and new column names to do this:

```
rename = dict(zip(df1.APIname, df1.Up_ApiName))
df = df.rename(columns=rename)
```